# Java Optional: check several alternatives (code more elegant)

Tags: java, option-type

I guess there's another more elegant way to write this code:

```
private boolean validateGicarHeaders(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return null != Optional.ofNullable(
           request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.GICAR_HEADER))
  .orElse(request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.HTTP_GICAR_HEADER));
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bad use of `Optional`, just use normal comparison and the `||`(OR) operator:

```
return 
    request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.GICAR_HEADER) != null || 
    request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.HTTP_GICAR_HEADER) != null;
```

Keep in mind, that `Optional` was introduced to indicate the absence of a *returned value* and not be used in branch-logic like `if`. (I sadly can't find a source that confirms this)

Answer (score 3):

Just keep it the old way:

```
return 
    request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.GICAR_HEADER) != null ||
    request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.HTTP_GICAR_HEADER) != null;
```

If you absolutely want to use some fancy Java8 feature, you can use `Streams`:

```
return Stream.of(
    request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.GICAR_HEADER),
    request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.HTTP_GICAR_HEADER)
).anyMatch(Objects::nonNull);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for `Optional` at all: just use a plain old null check.

```
return request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.GICAR_HEADER) != null
    || request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.HTTP_GICAR_HEADER) != null;
```

Answer (score -2):

As people stated already, its unnecessary - and not really nice way. But if you really really really wanted to do this check on Optionals, you could do it like this.

```
Optional.ofNullable( 
    Optional.ofNullable( request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.GICAR_HEADER) )
    .orElse( request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.HTTP_GICAR_HEADER) ) ).isPresent();
```

Comment: @Lino oops, I thought I copied the whole request - then again, it shouldn't be used anyways :v